# Internationalization (i18n) of whole spring boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, internationalization

What is best practice do make whole site internationalized ? I would like my site to be default Danish and to support other languages. I want to achieve is that my site is http://www.sitename.com/da/home and this means that site is in Danish. When user clicks on English flag to change site to http://www.sitename.com/en/home and from that point every page is in English language ?

Answer (score 0):

Externalize all your text resources to properties files in your java/resources folder and then configure a [LocaleChangeInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html) bean in the Spring configuration.

Comment: Can you help me how to implement behavior that when user click on other language, whole site and every page get translated into that language ?

Comment: @user3364181 You can follow [this guide](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization), it explains what I pointed you.